# Differences between 'He tells a lie to me' and 'He lies to me'

Tags: difference, phrase-usage

What are the differences between these below?

- He tells a lie to me
- He lies to me

Comment: I would rather phrase the first sentence "He tells me a lie." Other than that indeed it's the number of lies told that is unspecified in the second case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He tells a lie to me

The above clearly ensures that it is just **one** lie that he tells her.

> He lies to me

This one means that he lies to her, no matter if it is the same lie over-and-over again, or different lies altogether.